# Corona Sdk looking for an Issue( Platform Collision )

Tags: sdk, lua, coronasdk, platform

I'm using the pre-Collision to get my Player go through the platform like this

```
local function PhysicsPreCo(self,event)
    local Type = event.other.Type
    local PlayerY = self.y
    local PlatY = event.other.y

    if Type == "Platform" then
      if PlayerY -8  > PlatY then event.contact.isEnabled = false ; print("H") end
    end
end
```

So until here everything is working my player go through the platform properly, but sometimes when I jump before the platform too early my player hits the Platform's left side rather to go through.

I thought to use the content widht and content height to identify the left side Platform and tell to the physics to go through when it hits it but I did not success to figure it out.

Any help will be appreciate thanks a lot :)

!

Comment: No one, have already had a probleme like that ?

Comment: Can u properly explain your question with a picture?

Comment: I can't put pictures, i've not enough reputation..
What did you not understand ?
The probleme it's like the event.contact is not happening, I think maybe I can't change my anchorY of my player I don't know why , that's working for my object even so

Comment: Areyou sure that your condition: "if(PlayerY -8  > PlatY)then" is true that time? Also check for the collision effects in debug/hybrid mode by writing physics.setDrawMode("debug") or physics.setDrawMode("hybrid").

Comment: No it's for that in reality I can't find the perfect number to tell :
When my player is behind the platform then "event.contact.isEnabled = false" so my player can go through, and when is on top "event.contact.isEnabled = true", so my player can't go through
Mostly my player go through the platform without problem but sometimes the event.contact.isEnabled = false is not calling because my number is not perfect maybe missing 0,1 or less so my player hits the platform's side and bug my game !
You know what I mean ? 
Thanks a lot for your time and your reply Krs

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial for collisions including one side collisions.
http://coronalabs.com/blog/2012/11/27/introducing-physics-event-contact/

There is a ready project demonstrating everything in work
https://www.dropbox.com/s/4rbltonmrp5xwri/PhysicsContact.zip

In order to run above code you need to add

```
graphicsCompatibility = 1
```

in config.lua-s content section.